# Minimum hfe requirements

Tags: arduino, pcb, current, amplifier, diodes

Is this the minimum voltage and current value for the said dc current gain.
Thanks [image]
https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfdatasheet_motorola/bc546_bc547_bc548.pdf

Comment: imran muhd - Hi, Please remember the [site rule](/help/referencing) which says that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. For online content, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked as a minimum (references for books / articles should include title, author(s), publisher, edition, page numbers etc. - a typical citation). Therefore please can you [edit] your question to include the original source webpage/PDF link for that image. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder

Comment: imran muhd - Hi, I see you added a link, but it is not the correct link. Compare the datasheet at that link, with the one you put into the question :( Please can you add the correct link? Thanks.

Comment: I see what you mean SamGibson ..

Comment: It's a mistake i made

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not, otherwise that would be stated.

It's the scenario in which the specified value was measured.

Take things specified in data sheets at face value. There's no "magical deeper meaning".

Answer (score 2):

It is the hFE range under the exact "test condition" just as it says.

If your application matches the test condition you can use the number directly. If (as is usually the case) your application is different you will have to try to figure out what that means for your application.

For example, if you want the transistor to have a Vce of (say) 250mV at 100mA Ic you will have to give it more Ib than Ic/70 = 1.4mA to guarantee that Vce. Another line on the datasheet says if you give it Ib = 10mA you will have 250mV Vce (or less) guaranteed. There is usually a curve of typical hFE vs. Ic that allows some extrapolation.

Answer (score 1):

Minimum values? Not for \$I_C=100mA\$.
 But for \$V_{CE}\$ one volt will be close to minimum - between 0V - 1V, \$H_{FE}\$ will be decreasing from stated values. When \$ V_{CE}>1V\$, \$H_{FE}\$ might be marginally higher than stated values.

At the bias point of \$V_{CE}=1V, I_C=100mA\$, the transistor is in its linear range; for example when used as an amplifier. You could expect that \$H_{FE}\$ will be near the stated value at lower collector current...one data sheet shows \$H_{FE}\$ constant over the range of 1mA - 100mA. From 100mA up to 500mA maximum, \$H_{FE}\$ is decreasing from the stated value.

Note that \$H_{FE}\$ can be "binned" into tighter ranges than 70-240, likely costing a bit more.